# Is DefaultClusterRenderer in android-maps-utils broken in v1.2.1?

Tags: google-maps, kotlin, android-maps-utils, cluster-manager

When trying to override any functions in DefaultClusterRenderer, it will not compile in v1.2.1. All seems ok in v1.1.0

In here I want to set colors to the clustericons, and overrides the `DefaultClusterRenderer` `onBeforeClusterItemRendered` to set the colors according to a value.

Following code fails with v1.2.1, is perfectly ok in v1.1.0

```
package no.rogo.emptyfuel.utilities.cluster

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.util.Log
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.BitmapDrawableEncoder
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.Cluster
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.view.DefaultClusterRenderer

import com.google.maps.android.ui.IconGenerator
import no.rogo.emptyfuel.R
import no.rogo.emptyfuel.utilities.StatusLevel

/**
 * Created by Roar on 05.04.2020.
 * Copyright RoGo Software / Gronmo IT
 */
class CustomClusterRenderer(
    context: Context,
    map: GoogleMap,
    clusterManager: ClusterManager<ClusterStation?>?
) : DefaultClusterRenderer<ClusterStation?>(context,map,clusterManager)
{
    private val TAG by lazy { this::class.java.simpleName }

    private val clusterIconGenerator = IconGenerator(context.applicationContext)

    override fun onBeforeClusterItemRendered(
        item: ClusterStation?,
        markerOptions: MarkerOptions?
    ) {

        var markerHue = when(item?.statusLevel)
        {
            StatusLevel.SINCE_NEW -> BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN
            StatusLevel.SINCE_FAIR -> BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW
            StatusLevel.SINCE_OLD -> BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED
            StatusLevel.SINCE_OLDER -> BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE
            StatusLevel.NOT_SET -> BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN
            StatusLevel.NOT_AVAILABLE -> BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE
            StatusLevel.HIDDEN -> BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE
            StatusLevel.UNCERTAIN -> BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE
            StatusLevel.UNKNOWN -> BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA
            else -> BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET
        }



        //Color.colorToHSV(markerColor,markerHue)

        //Log.i(TAG,"map3: markerHue = ${markerHue[0]}")

        val markerDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(markerHue)
        markerOptions?.icon(markerDescriptor)

        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions)
    }

    override fun onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem: ClusterStation?, marker: Marker?) {
        super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker)
    }

    override fun onBeforeClusterRendered(
        cluster: Cluster<ClusterStation?>?,
        markerOptions: MarkerOptions?
    ) {
        super.onBeforeClusterRendered(cluster, markerOptions)
    }


}
```

Do any know what has changed, and how to fix ?

RG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem, in this pull (https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/pull/687) they changed the parameters to be nullsafe, so when changing:

```
override fun onBeforeClusterItemRendered(
    item: ClusterStation?,
    markerOptions: MarkerOptions?
)
```

to

```
override fun onBeforeClusterItemRendered(
    item: ClusterStation, 
    markerOptions: MarkerOptions
)
```

fixed it. It is actually a kotlin issue...

RG